# Meaning of "may I be twice damned for a bank-clerk or store hand" in "I hight Don Quixote", a poem by Jack Parsons

Tags: meaning, poetry, jack-parsons

From *[I Hight Don Quixote](https://hermetic.com/parsons/i-hight-don-quixote-i-live-on-peyote)* by [Jack Parsons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Parsons_(rocket_engineer)):

> They said I was crazy, ambiguous, lazy,
> disgusting, fantastic, obscene;
> So I hied for my sagebrush and cactus and corn mush,
> To see if the air was still clean.
> Oh, I hight Don Quixote, I live on peyote,
> marihuana, morphine and cocaine,
> And **may I be twice damned for a bank-clerk or store hand**
> if I visit the city again.

What is the meaning of "may I be twice damned for a bank-clerk or store hand"?

Does he mean: "I may do something to a bank clerk or store hand, and be damned for this"? Or "I may be mistaken for a bank clerk or store hand"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

He emphatically will not visit the city again.

> *I’m damned if*
>
> informal
>
> Used to say that you will certainly not do something
>
> “I’m polite to his ex-wife when I meet her, but I’m damned if I’m going to invite her over for dinner”

Source: [I'm damned if](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/i-m-damned-if) in the Cambridge English Dictionary.

He’s saying, “I swear that I will not visit the city again, and as proof that I will not break this oath, if I *do* break this oath then I ask to be damned to live the doubly-hellish (“twice damned”) life of a bank clerk or shop worker”. There’s a secondary meaning of “if I were to return to the city then I would have to live the doubly-hellish life of a person who lives in the city”.

In other words, his punishment for returning to the city would be the fact of having to live in the city, which would be like being sent to Hell then being sent from there to an even worse Hell.

It’s clever and witty, I like it a lot.